# SQL views from one table

Tags: sql-server, filter, view

My colleague asked me a question regarding getting data from a SQL Server database.

I have a sample data set

```
[ID],[TOWN],[PERSON]
[1],[BELFAST],[JAMES]
[2],[NEWRY],[JOHN]
[3],[BELFAST],[SIMON]
[4],[LARNE],[ALAN]
```

Now from this I would like to return a SQL Dataset that returns me a different table based upon the view.

Essentially in code I could get a distinct on the town then loop sql filtering on the town.  But is there a way I can do this in SQL?

Where I would get (3) views back (2 Belfast, 1 Newry and 1 Larne)

Basicly I it would return

```
[ID],[Town],[Person]
[1],[Belfast],[James]
[3],[Belfast],[Simon]
```

Then another view would return for 'Larne' and a Final one for Newry.  Basically SQL creating views for each town it finds and then returns the records for each town.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (then you don't need any of those pesky `<br/>` tags, either!)

Comment: I have difficulties to understand what exactly you want. Could you also post an example of the output you want to have?

Comment: Done and thanks for formatting.

Comment: Are you sure about that.  A Dataset Can Return Multiple Tables and If I can remember correctly Oracle can do the same also

Comment: @TheMonkeyMan: SQL Server **isn't** Oracle .... (for better or worse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I have decided to Run it as a Stored Procedure to return me each item as a List.  So something along the lines of this:

```
Create Procedure ListTowns
As
declare @towns char(11)

select @towns = (select distinct Town from [Towns])

while @towns is not null <> 0
begin
    select * from [YourTable] where Town = @towns
end
```

Comment: Exactly my question `ForWhy`? Mostly because I can't see the big picture. You've not explained what it is you're doing with the data and why you need it returned in this way. It seems, well, a bit odd at this point.

Comment: Basically because my college wants it to return a DataSet with which he can generate 3 datatables on the Fly with data and bind them to the screen.  Basically.  Here is all the Towns in the System and Records Stored with these towns.  Its for a Report I believe.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question, you simply need to create a view for each town you want to filter:

```
CREATE VIEW BelfastView AS

SELECT    ID,
          Town,
          Person
FROM      YourTable
WHERE     Town = 'BELFAST'
```

Although you've only given us a small sample of your data, what you're asking is almost never a good idea. What happens when you have 50 new towns in your DB? Are you going to create a view for each town? This does not scale well (or at all).

Answer (score 1):

You don't *get views back* - you have to define them yourself.

E.g. if you need one view for Belfast, a second for Newry and a third for Larne - then you need to **create** three views that return only those rows that match the relevant city name

```
 CREATE VIEW BelfastView 
 AS 
    SELECT ID, Town, Person
    FROM dbo.Towns
    WHERE Town = 'Belfast'

 CREATE VIEW LarneView 
 AS 
    SELECT ID, Town, Person
    FROM dbo.Towns
    WHERE Town = 'Larne'

 CREATE VIEW NewryView 
 AS 
    SELECT ID, Town, Person
    FROM dbo.Towns
    WHERE Town = 'Newry'
```

Now, certain users might only be allowed to select data from the `BelfastView` and thus would never see any other rows of data from your underlying table.

But views are **database objects** like tables or stored procedures; you need to create them, maintain them, toss them when no longer needed.